# Pass input with route id to controller method together

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to create input with game amount. User will write how many copy of concrete game wants to buy. Then two parameters will pass to AddToCart method. First will be gameId like below (it works well) and user amount input. How to pass these two values together into controller method?

View:

@model IEnumerable

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/productcards.css">
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var game in Model)
        {


            <div class="col-md-3">

                <div class="product-grid">

                    <div class="product-image">
                        <a asp-controller="Game" asp-action="ShowDetails" asp-route-productId=@game.GameId>
                            <img class="pic-1" src="~/images/@game.ImagePath">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-content">
                        <h3 class="title">
                            <a asp-controller="Game" asp-action="ShowDetails" asp-route-productId=@game.GameId>@game.Title</a>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="price">@game.Price.ToString() zł</div>
                            <a asp-controller="Cart" asp-action="AddToCart" asp-route-gameId="@game.GameId" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i> KUP</a>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        }

    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
   public RedirectToActionResult AddToCart(int gameId)
    {
        var selectedGame = _appDbContext.Games.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GameId == gameId);

        if(selectedGame != null)
        {
            _cart.AddToCart(selectedGame, 1);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your view like below:

```
@foreach (var game in Model)
{
<form method="post">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="product-grid">
            <div class="product-content">
                <h3 class="title">
                    <a asp-controller="Game" asp-action="ShowDetails" asp-route-productId=@game.GameId>@game.Title</a>
                </h3>
                <div class="price">@game.Price.ToString() zł</div>

                <div class="amount"><input name="amount" type="number" /></div>  @*add this line*@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
          @*change <a> to <input> and add a <form>*@
        <input type="submit" asp-route-gameId="@game.GameId" asp-controller="Cart" asp-action="AddToCart" class="btn btn-primary" value="KUP"/>
    </div>
</form>
}
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult AddToCart(int gameId,int amount)
{
    //do your stuff...
}
```

Result:
[image]